# How can i solve this nested tableview scenario

Tags: ios, uitableview

I've got a fairly simple scenario:

The data structure i am expecting essentially looks like this (the actual layout is way more complicated):

- some title

  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
- some title

  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
- some title

  - n child text
- some title

  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text
  - n child text

In my first attempt i rendered all of it using programmed constraints, which (as you might guess) worked, but performed really bad.

Naturally i went ahead and researched for ways to display dynamic nested content. Unfortunately i was unable to find a good generic way to do this, using cell recycling.

Now i just came up with an idea which seemed very creative, but uber hacky.

## What i am going to do, to utilize cell recycling:

I will create a generic cell class to pass `TableView.RegisterClassForCellReuse(typeof(MySpecialCell<ItemType, RandomTypeForUniqueness>), "MySpecialCell"+item.Count.ToString());`

Setup my cell depending on child count.

## My question:

Is there a less cringy way to solve this? (Because this sure feels ugly.)

This is what it should look like in the end:

[image: this is what it is supposed to be layouted like]

PS: I really wish RegisterClassForCellReuse would accept factories :(

Comment: The simple data structure you show us in the question can be shown using a simple table view using sections. Each "some title" would be the section's title and each "child text" is just a row in that section. Since that's too obvious and simple, your needs must be more complex but you don't tell us anything about your actual data.

Comment: @maddy I've attached an image from the mockup now. Not sure if that is doable with section headers. (I'm developing this with xamarin.iOS and i'm not really an iOS developer)

Comment: also i am not really sure why someone would downvote me - like i said i know a way to solve my problem - i just wonder if there is a better way to do so

Comment: Nothing about the screen you posted indicates that you should use a nested table view. If I were to do that I would create a custom view that can draw each "section". That custom view would have "Beschreibung", "Summe", and the graph. Now you can use a table view where each cell contains one of those custom views.

Comment: @rmaddy i tried that approach as well previously. unfortunately in that case i too ran into performance issues due to the amount of constraints + lack of cell recycling. Thanks for the input though

Comment: What lack of cell recycling? You must have done it incorrectly.

Comment: @rmaddy i am sure i am doing something wrong. other apps seem to get it done somehow. could you give me a few pointers in chat? the whole reason my current approach is like this, is because with purely custom + generated controls performance was really bad because i was building the whole layout using programmed constraints (it worked, but the performance was really poor) which is why i was hoping for a performance increase through using a tableview with cell recycling

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps:

In .h , declare

```
NSMutableArray  *arrayForBool;
NSMutableArray *arrPastOrder;
```

In .m ,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

arrPastOrder=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

int range=1+arc4random()%10;
for(int i=0;i<range;i++)
{
    NSMutableArray *arrinside=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    int range2=3+arc4random()%5;

    for(int j=0;j<range2;j++)
    {
        if(j==0)
            [arrinside addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Some Header %i",i]];
        else
            [arrinside addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Subindex %i",j]];

    }

    [arrPastOrder addObject:arrinside];

}

arrayForBool=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

for (int i=0; i<[arrPastOrder count]; i++)
{
    [arrayForBool addObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES]];
}
  }



#pragma mark -
#pragma mark TableView DataSource and Delegate Methods

   - (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {

   if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:section] boolValue])
    {
    return  [[arrPastOrder objectAtIndex:section] count]-1;
    }
   else
    return 0;

   }

    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath: (NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {


    static NSString *cellid=@"hello";

    UITableViewCell *cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];

   if (cell==nil)
   {
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellid];
      }


BOOL manyCells  = [[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue];

/********** If the section supposed to be closed *******************/
if(!manyCells)
{
    cell.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];

    NSLog(@"cellForRowAtIndexPath---if");

    cell.textLabel.text=@"";
}
/********** If the section supposed to be Opened *******************/
else
{

    //cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %ld",[sectionTitleArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section],indexPath.row+1];


    //  ic_keyboard_arrow_up_48pt_2x  ic_keyboard_arrow_down_48pt_2x.png

    cell.textLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrPastOrder objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row+1]];


}

cell.textLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];

return cell;

}


 - (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
 {
    return [arrPastOrder count];

  }

     - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {


    NSLog(@"%li--%li",(long)indexPath.section, (long)indexPath.row);

  }


    - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
      {
       if ([[arrayForBool objectAtIndex:indexPath.section] boolValue]) {
         return 40;
      }
        return 0;

       }

     - (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {
          return 100;
     }

   #pragma mark - Creating View for TableView Section

    - (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
     {

UIView *sectionView=[[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 540,100)];
sectionView.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
sectionView.tag=section;

UILabel *viewLabel=[[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10, 30, 530, 40)];
viewLabel.backgroundColor=[UIColor whiteColor];
viewLabel.textColor=[UIColor blackColor];
viewLabel.font=[UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:20];
viewLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[arrPastOrder objectAtIndex:section] objectAtIndex:0]];
[sectionView addSubview:viewLabel];



/********** Add UITapGestureRecognizer to SectionView   **************/

UITapGestureRecognizer  *headerTapped   = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(sectionHeaderTapped:)];
[sectionView addGestureRecognizer:headerTapped];

return  sectionView;


 }


 #pragma mark - Table header gesture tapped

 - (void)sectionHeaderTapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer{

    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:gestureRecognizer.view.tag];    

   //Get which section is open, from here Set the value of arrafool. and expand collapse. Normally whole table is expanded. 


 }
```

Just run it. You will get the same structure.  happy Coding !!